# Android studio keeps reverting code / deleting

Tags: java, android-studio

After adding new line of code and clicking run app all the new code is deleted for some reason and only the old code remains
I don't know what is causing the automatically revert or deletions please help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by clean project then rebuild project
Thank all!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it keep deleting new code on a file as soon as I saved it. In my case, it was because I opened the same project in another instance of Android Studio with the same tab opened. I close one of the two and didn't give me the problem.